# Universal (EXE/Web) .NET config reader

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, exe

I need to write a .NET 4.5 component which potentially can be used by .EXE or Web applications. This component has a number of configuration parameters to be provided - in main app.config or web.config accordingly. 
Is there an universal API to read config or at least a way to determine the mode?

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Configuration.Abstractions` library from [David Whitney](http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/) works across both desktop and web applications. You can install it with nuget:

```
install-package System.Configuration.Abstractions
```

There's documentation on the [Github site](https://github.com/davidwhitney/System.Configuration.Abstractions), but in a nutshell where you'd use `ConfigurationManager` or `WebConfigurationManager`, you can instead use `System.Configuration.Abstractions.ConfigurationManager.Instance` (or use IConfigurationManager and inject an instance)

Answer (score 0):

For App.config (desktop applications, foo.exe.config) use:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

For Web.config, you need to use:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Abstract both of these and you're covered.

To determine whether or not you're in an ASP.NET environment, I have used `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.IsHosted` in the past.